# How to multiply two columns in pandas, by only non-NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, multiplication

I am curious if it is possible to multiply two columns `A,B` by only non NAN values.

I have the following dataframe with the expected results:

```
                         A     B     C
    Date     Symbol  

  1/1/2017    BTC       Nan    2     Nan
              ETH        3     Nan   6
              XRP        2     Nan   4
  1/2/2017    BTC       Nan    3     Nan
              ETH        1     Nan    3
              XRP        2     Nan    6
```

I am trying to multiply non Nan values of column `A` by non-NaN values of Column `B` and assign the result to column `C`.
I want to iterate over the dataframe. I have tried few things, but nothing is working.

Comment: What result are you expecting if there are multiple non-nan values in a single column of one of the groups?

Comment: I want to multiply each non Nan value in column A by non Nan value of column B and pass the result in column C for symbols that have non Nan values in column A.

Comment: What would like you stored in `C` if either/both of `A,B` are NaN? Do you want NaN output, or keep the current value of `C`?

Comment: It's a little confusing, as *none* of your rows have non-null values for both A and B, which according to your described logic should mean everything in C should be null.

Comment: Yeah, you should provide a better example where some rows have neither NaN, and some both NaN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `ffill`

```
#df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)# Nan is not NaN , replace it 
#df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,1) # convert to numeric 
df.C=df.A*(df.B.ffill())
df
Out[130]: 
                   A    B    C
Date     Symbol               
1/1/2017 BTC     NaN  2.0  NaN
         ETH     3.0  NaN  6.0
         XRP     2.0  NaN  4.0
1/2/2017 BTC     NaN  3.0  NaN
         ETH     1.0  NaN  3.0
         XRP     2.0  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: [`ffill` is more commonly known as `fillna(..., method='ffill')`. That's also a more self-explanatory name.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html). Actually, I don't think forward/back-filling is correct in this use-case, it will give the wrong answer.

Comment: @smci let us wait for the op and thank you for you additional information

Comment: Forward/back-filling is clearly the wrong thing to do, you will be wrongly using rows with NaNs, and (worse still) just making up values from previous rows (which we already know the OP doesn't want).

Comment: @smci I will waiting for op for clarify, so far just simple match his output

Comment: Wen-Ben: oh, my apologies, I thought OP's column `C` shown was just input junk, yeah in that case you're probably right, we'll have to wait for their confirmation (and a more comprehensive testcase). I'll fix it to an upvote once OP edits to clarify, and then if you make a token edit on this answer to unlock my vote. Argh...

Comment: @Wen-Ben thank you so much for your solution. It perfectly worked for me.

Comment: @rakamakafo: but then you want forward-filling of NaNs, in each column? Please confirm (edit the question above to explicitly say that)? What about the case where all preceding values in a column are also NaN, is that a don't-care (like your first rows for each date)?

Answer (score 0):

````
df = pd.DataFrame(data=obj)
df['t'] = (df['col1'].ffill())* (df['col2'].ffill())```

   col1  col2    t
0   1.0   3.0  3.0
1   2.0   4.0  8.0
2   1.0   NaN  4.0
3   NaN   8.0  8.0
````

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**